# Extending Type with new property isn't working

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add one property to an existing Type. Here's my type:

```
const dialogData: DialogData = {
    a: string,
    b: string,
    c: string
}
```

I extend it like this:

```
export type ExtendedDialogData = DialogData & {
    d: number
}
```

But when I try to create the object it's failing. My syntax must be completely wrong:

```
const myData: DialogData[{a:0, b:1, c:2}, {a:3, b:4, c:5}]
const myExtendedData: ExtendedDialogData[] = [...myData, d: 100 ];
```

The error is on *d* and says *cannot find name 'd'*. Also, in actuality, I just want *d* to be a copy of whatever *c* is. Can someone please help me understand my syntax error?

UPDATE: As requested, here's the real code. In a Material dialog in Angular I have these two types:

```
export type EditableDataModel = MyDataModel & {
    sharesToMove: MyDataModel[];
}

export interface MyOrdersDialogData {
    title: string,
    orders: EditableDataModel[]
}
```

In the component that launches the model, I have this:

```
public launchModal() {
    const orders: EditableDataModel[] = [...this.selectedOrders.map(el => {...el, sharesToMove: el.shares})[;
}
```

I can console.log inside the map and see the orders output like this:

```
{
    title: 'my title', 
    orders: 1556
}
```

Comment: There are [quite a few problems](https://tsplay.dev/wRX8Lm) with this code; could you make sure you are presenting a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE?  Right now I can't tell what part is broken because it's pseudocode and what part is broken because it's your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you are trying to add `d` directly to the array instead of adding to each object inside the array. You can try like the following

```
const myData: DialogData[{a:0, b:1, c:2}, {a:3, b:4, c:5}]
const myExtendedData: ExtendedDialogData[] = [...myData.map(el => ({...el, d: 100})) ];
```

This will add the d property to each item in the array